# WPF binding on generic list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 project, using MVVM, I bind an object to the View. That object has a generic list which I need to bind on a `LongListSelector`. Since I cant convert my list to observable, how can I bind it and have a `TwoWay` update?

Example of my object:

Class: `Person`

Properties:

- `ID` - `int`
- `Name` - `string`
- `Groups` - List of `Groups`. This is the property I need to bind on the `LongListSelector`

.

### ## UPDATE 1: ##

In short my problem is that I have an object with a List as navigation property (not observable collection). What is the Best Practice when you want to bind that List Navigation Property on the View.

Comment: I guess you mean `ObservableCollection`. In order to bind to the `Groups` property, it is not necessary that it is an `ObservableCollection<Group>`. You can bind to any `IEnumerable<Group>`, hence also to `List<Group>`. The only drawback is that the LongListSelector is not automatically updated when items are added to or removed from the collection. You may not need that, though.

Comment: Sorry I lost you. Groups in Person is a Generic List in deed List<Group>. I didn't make it ObservableCollection since there are reasons that I need my POCO to be List and not ObservableCollection. I have LongListSelector in other Views which are bind on ObservableColection and works fine. Is there any way to Bind the Person.Groups as is (List) on the LongListSelector and still have the TwoWay binding?

Comment: Yes of course, you can simply bind to the `Groups` property. The LongListSelector will show the items that are initially contained in the Groups list. However, if you later add items to the list, the binding will not automatically update the LongListSelector to show the new items (that is what `ObservableCollection` does). And I'm not sure what you mean with TwoWay binding here? Does a LongListSelector allow to change the items collection, i.e. add or remove items?

Comment: I do the bind now, and as you correctly said, it only shows the list of groups the first time. Them I have a Context kind of menu where I add or delete groups for that person. I need some kind of technique to update my View when changes (add or delete) happen on Person.Groups

Comment: @YiannisStavrianos Do you know when your list changes?

Comment: ... just to clarify, TwoWay is the WPF mode when you need the changes on the object reflect the UI and vice versa. In my case OneWay (only the changes on the list from code) would also be fine.

Comment: @CédricBignon as it is now, no I don't know when the list changes.

Comment: @YiannisStavrianos Except by refreshing regularly your list (in a smart way) you can't achieve this without an `ObservableCollection` instead of a list.

Comment: @CédricBignon that's what I was afraid that the answer would be. On the other hand I guessed that my issue would be common since it is very often to have navigation property as a List and not ObservableCollection. What is the best practice for this case?

Comment: @YiannisStavrianos The best practice is MVVM (to long to describe it here). Just a question, why do you need a `List` and can't change it to `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @CédricBignon the person object is part of my wider Business Logic object and as a rule I have my collections to be List. I prefere not to change on case just because it is more convenient in the UI.

Comment: @YiannisStavrianos just implement INotifypropertychanged on your groups ..it will all work fine..the main difference between observableCollection and genericlist it that the former one already had implemented INotifypropertyChanged .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all comments from the guys, I ended up that it was inevitable after all to insist with generic list. I changed my list to ObservableCollection and everything is ok now.

I guess the answer credits should go to Clemens, Cédric Bignon and tanuj_loop